# How do I find the public URL of the RStudio connect server?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio-server, reproducible-research

I am trying to publish an RMarkdown document that I have edited in RStudio. but it's unfortunate that I am quite confused the way I need to go about this publishment.
I am requested to **Enter the Public URL of the RStudio Connect server:**
I searched through internet, how I can find this URL but I have failed to find it. I even filled the form on https://rstudio.com/products/connect/ but did not yield any positive result.

Kindly help to know what is wrong with my Rstudio connect and what I do to address this issue.

thank you in advance!

Below is the the screenshot of the message I am being given.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mOGT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the error I was experiencing is due to the location of the project location (directory) I am working with which was different from the current directory.

In addition to this, I found that I needed to knit the document to html before proceeding to publishing it.

The issue has been now addressed, thanks!